# Showing error messages on form without shifting layout?

Tags: forms, layout

I have a form where I want to show some errors (like "Email field required"). What I currently have is a red error message under the description (like shown below).

The issue is, when the error appears, the layout shifts to make space for the error. It's not the worst thing in the world but I'd prefer to avoid layout movement.

What I'm considering:

- Just leave as is and make the users a bit annoyed
- Leave some space for the error but keep the form item far from the next item (not sure what to do if the error needs 2 lines)
- When I show the error, hide the description

What do you think?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the case, you can match the description with the alert and simply show the color change on the error:

[image]

Comment: This seems like a nice middle ground, maybe even add some error information to it. So if I have enough space, it won't make the layout shift. Like "Enter collection name. Minimum size is 4 characters"

Answer (score 0):

So you can make use of the `visibility` CSS property.

With it you can create the error message below the description and set the `visibility` CSS prop to `hidden`. This is the same as setting the `opacity` to 0.

The best part is that you probably already have code that's doing the layout shift, you just add this to your CSS and you good to go.

Personally, I prefer the layout shift, it lets the user know they've done something wrong somewhere, but I've also been a bit put off by it at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, technically I know how to implement all. I'm more considering how to do it.

Comment: @ArturCarvalho Ah I see, this was just my opinion on how to get to what you want. No DOM thrashing if people still worry about that.